# D-Brane charge (IIB string theory)

Tags: charge, string-theory, branes

Can someone please give a detailed explanation of what the D-brane charge is?

In particle physics and gauge theory, The charge of a particle can be obtained by taking the integral of a closed surface surrounding the charge. In the $D=4$ case, we can consider a surface $S^2$ surrounding particle and by evaluating $\int_{S^2} F$ we get the charge. I think a similar approach is there for D-branes but it's not totally clear to me. I would like to get an answer regarding D-branes in Type IIB string theory compactified on the Calabi-Yau manifold if possible.